Tearing diaphragms on Saunders/Crane 1.5'' EC actuator valve (6 - 8 bar normally closed)

I am having torn diaphragms on my skids (used in pharmaceutical production plant). The tears are coming from 1.5" actuator valves (Saunders/crane EC type actuator normally closed, air to open [6 - 8 bar]). We are getting adequate air to close the diaphragms.
There is adequate flow through the weir and the weir has the correct RA (not scratched/damaged). We see one torn diaphragm about every two weeks, and it causes unwanted downtime. We don't think we have a vacuum causing suction thus tearing the diaphragm, but not for certain. Sometimes we have high pressure situations.  But we are having trouble finding the link between high pressure and tearing diaphragms. The diaphragms are PTFE with EPDM backing. They don't see temperatures or pressures outside of their operating parameters per the vendors documents. Some pictures are below.
What could be causing these tears?
